# Database playground

Tags: beginner, sql, bash, linux

This is my very first interaction with databases. The goal is to setup a safe playground on an Arch box to create tables and make queries.  I want to learn the basics without risking `sudo rm -rf /`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash


# This script initializes a new MariaDB database,
# without root privileges,
# and connects to it.
# Learn SQL!
# Pre-requisetes: `pacman -Syu mariadb`


# Utility function.
# This also exists in `../bashrc/funcs`.
function run
{
    cd /tmp
    nohup "$@" &
    cd -
}


# Unprivilliged install.
# For production this should be in `/opt`,
# but this here is just for learning so let's be safe.
DB_DIR="/home/$(id -u -n)/.sql/dat"
SOCKET_DIR="/run/user/$(id -u)/mariadbtest"
SOCKET="$SOCKET_DIR/mysql.socket"


# Create a DB if running for the first time.
if [ ! -d "$DB_DIR" ]
then
mysql_install_db --datadir="$DB_DIR"
fi


# Run the server if not running already.
mkdir -p "$SOCKET_DIR"
pidof mysqld
if [ ! "$?" ]
then
run mysqld --socket="$SOCKET" --datadir="$DB_DIR"
fi


# Connect to the db.
mysql --socket="$SOCKET"


# Get started.
# show schemas like "%";
# show full tables from information_schema;
```

Comment: You can't risk `rm -rf /`; GNU rm (the one in Arch Linux) requires a `--no-preserve-root` flag.

Comment: @S.S.Anne it was a figure of speech. To reword, `I want to avoid doing things I  don't understand as root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Good stuff

- lots of good comments
- indenting your function definition
- putting variables inside of double quotes when you use them

## Suggestions

- indent between `then` and `fi`, as you would in other languages with conditionals
- combine `then` with `if` line using `;`
- use `[[` forms of conditionals to avoid surprises

Those three things would lead to code like:

```
if [[ ! -d "$DB_DIR" ]]; then
    mysql_install_db --datadir="$DB_DIR"
fi
```

Then I would:

- put the definitions for `DB_DIR`, `SOCKET_DIR`, and `SOCKET` above the function `run`.  These are things somebody might like to edit later so putting them near the top will make it easier to find.
- add error checking to the `mkdir` like `mkdir -p "$SOCKET_DIR" || exit 1`
- try [bash strict mode](http://redsymbol.net/articles/unofficial-bash-strict-mode/)
- try [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)
- read [google's shell style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html)

Comment: You are awesome!! I [refactored](https://github.com/MiroslavVitkov/scripts/blob/master/db/init.sh) whatever I can.

Comment: Happy to help out.  I'm also glad to see you are using github.  It looks good.